# How to keep Rails form POST data after devise authentication when storing in a session is too small?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've been around the houses on this and I'm sure I'm approaching this the wrong way.

On my RoR site, users can enter details for a new post if they are logged out. But when they hit 'Create' I check if they are authenticated or not. If they are not, I ask the user to log in or create an account. Once logged in, I want the form to resubmit automatically with the original POST data. I'm using devise for authentication.

I have everything working, except retaining the original form POST data and avoiding a CSRF fail.

I think the CSRF fail is because the resubmitted data does not have the authenticity token - so I've turned off CSRF protection for now, until I fix the 
POST data retention.

I can't store the data in the session as the form data includes an image and breaks the 4k session limit.

Please, is there a regular Rails pattern that solves this problem?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: take authenticity token from new form (which you re-request after user logs in) and send it with the old request data.

Comment: I think that won't work as I can't store the old request data in the session (data too big as it includes an image) and i want this to work as much as possible with AJAX.